# Can we change border color of mat-checkbox in angular?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

In my project black theme we are using so, need to show checkbox border color with white border. But, css is not working in checkbox and border color is not changing.

Is there any way to change the border color of mat-checkbox? I am using angular material checkbox that link I have written below.

[image: Checkbox Image]

[Angular material checkbox](https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/overview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
::ng-deep .custom-checkbox .mat-checkbox-frame {
  border-color: #ff0000 !important;  /* Change this to the desired color */
}


<mat-checkbox
  class="custom-checkbox"
  color="primary"
>
  Check me!</mat-checkbox
>
```

Answer (score 2):

The below CSS seems to do the job, kindly change it based on your requirements!

```
.mdc-checkbox
  .mdc-checkbox__native-control:enabled
  ~ .mdc-checkbox__background {
  border-color: red !important;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/1gutg7?file=src%2Fstyles.scss)